# How to slideup the Div on Document Press using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

**Style**

```
#panel,#flip
{
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
background-color:#e5eecc;
border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
padding:50px;
display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Here is the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JkQR2/

Hi. How to slideup the Div on Document Press using Jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a document click event handler and check the event target is not #flip:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if(!$(e.target).is("#flip")) {
           $("#panel").slideUp(); 
        }
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/CDXuM/)

Answer (score 1):

here's a little code that you need to in need of slideUp the Div on Document Press using jQuery.

**Solution :**  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/JkQR2/3/)

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#flip").click(function(){
             $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
         });
        $(document).click(function(event) {
            if(!$(event.target).is("#flip")) {
                $("#panel").slideUp(); 
            }
        });
     });
```

Comment: Your Demo does not show the code above, and the code above won't work. Document is an object, not a selector

Comment: Yeah, I have changed it according to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add the click event to diocumnet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).click(function(){
     $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```